# how to share android studio application folder to program with two computers

Tags: android, android-studio, github, share, dropbox

First of all, hello !

I'm learning to program with android studio 2.1 (2.2 preview also) and and have a question.

How I can share the app folder (in dropbox, drive, or other free cloud service) to be able to make changes with my home computer and also with my laptop when I am out ?

I read something about github, but I mean it's not free. An now I'm a beginner and will not spend money at the moment.

Thank's !

Answer (score 0):

You can try Radmin(full remote control) or make ftp server from your computer.  Also you can make a project folder in Dropbox folder in destktop version of Dropbox(did not tried, but may to work)

Comment: Hello Bogdan.
I will have my home computer off when use the laptop.
When I save the project into a dropbox folder the both Android Studio (home and laptop) can open the project but I'm not sure if all right, because both shows some error/advice's messages.
Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Atlassian's Bitbucket](https://www.atlassian.com/software/bitbucket). This allows private & free repositories.